# Using auto increment id value to update hash_id column

Tags: mysql

I have `hash_id` column in my table and I want to have it set on every insert so it's `MD5(id)` of just inserted row. How to do it in one insert query?

Comment: What have you tried? How does your table look? Please provide more information.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an after insert trigger to do this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER md5MyId AFTER INSERT ON {sometable}
FOR EACH ROW SET md5id=MD5(NEW.id) WHERE id=NEW.id;
```

That way the MD5 will be created during the `INSERT` by using the newly generated id.

*Code not tested*, so try and test first.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a column `id` that is auto increment in the table you need, and create a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) `AFTER INSERT` where is updates the hash_id column of the inserted row with md5(id).

Comment: so what is the down vote for?? I bet this is the same as the other answer which did not get a downvote!!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe: The other answer showed how to write the trigger, instead of leaving it as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @Barmar You think writing non tested code solution would be better hah!! Besides the OP did not provide much detials and my asnwer gave a solution to put him on track...